# Preventing users from accessing Application Database

Tags: sql-server

We have a problem where one of our customers is changing data directly in the database.

As we have an API, we'd prefer our customers to use this. We have threatened not to support their solution if they persist in manually changing data.

My query is, is there a technical way we can prevent access to the database from anything other than our application?

This is a sql server database, and our customers own the server and administer the DB server, So essentially we need a way to lock out SA.

Thanks

Comment: Clarification: it is Sysadmin users who are accessing the database directly. They are editing business data on the tables. One option that we are looking at is putting triggers on all the tables, but these would need to replicate complex business rules and workflows we'd prefer to keep in the app code

Comment: Based on your licensing data comment, your most reasonable option is to encrypt the sensitive data on the database and decrypt the data in the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things... you can't:

- lock out sa or sysadmin rights at all at the server level
- lock out db_owner/dbo at the database level

Now we've cleared that one up, who is accessing data directly?

- If you mean end users are changing data, then you have a security issue: they should only be able to use the API and not even be able to connect.
- If you mean sysadmin level users (eg DBAs or BOFH types) then there may be a legitimate reason. Does your API support all operations? As a DBA, I had to do open table surgery on badly written 3rd party apps now and then
- If end users have sysadmin level rights, then you have a politics issue within the client company

Edit:

After comment by OP on their question... sysadmin users can disable triggers...

Comment: Added clarification comment on the question. It is sysadmin I want to lock out. While our primary concern is data integrity, we also have reason to believe that one of our customers is trying to fiddle with licencing data (based on number of users, and some other domain specific issues). We do have export functonality, so there's no vendor lock-in issues.

Comment: Are your sysadmins trying to give you a big hint that they want the database to police itself rather than your having the logical/business integrity checks in the client app?

Comment: @Tim It's not 'our' sysadmins, its our customers sysadmins. Our app does make use of Stored Procedures and constraints. The sysadmins are changing the data on the tables, not running the stored procedures. As per comment above, we could put triggers everywhere, but 1: as per @gbn's edit, it wouldn't be any use, and 2: Where do you draw the line between database and application?

Answer (score 1):

Is you API public? It shouldn't be if you can change data without any authentication. I recommend using some internal authentication mechanism. A basic challenge/response protocol that ensures that the incoming query is safe to execute, or something like that.